# Android :How do i force Retrofit to use port 80 as a part of the Base url

Tags: android, http, retrofit, port

I have this base url http://example.com:80/ but when i make a Retrofit call it is delete ":80" from the base url and become : http://example.com/ so the result is 404 Not Found.
I know that port 80 is the Default port for **http** protocol so the question is : **how can i make a retrofit call  with this Base url.**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry it was a  server error it was give me response for any request 404 so Retrofit working ok  even it  delete ":80"  from Base url